# Concatenate text to single String every time user writes in Edit Text

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to add text from Edit Text into single string every time user writes something and presses the button.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 vendor_add_tags_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (vendor_profile_enter_tags.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileSetup.this, "Please enter any tags", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                mTagContainerLayout.addTag(vendor_profile_enter_tags.getText().toString());
                if (!vendor_profile_enter_tags.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    sw.append(vendor_profile_enter_tags.getText().toString());
                    String tags = sw.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(this, tags, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                vendor_profile_enter_tags.getText().clear();
                mTagContainerLayout.setTheme(ColorFactory.NONE);

            }

        });
```

I am very new to android please some help.

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: @AgentP This code only saves the current text and displays it, but i want to concatenate every text user writes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a StringWriter instance every time when it gets clicked. So Instead of having it as local make it global

```
final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

 vendor_add_tags_btn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (vendor_profile_enter_tags.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileSetup.this, "Please enter any tags", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                mTagContainerLayout.addTag(vendor_profile_enter_tags.getText().toString());
                if (!vendor_profile_enter_tags.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    sw.append(vendor_profile_enter_tags.getText().toString());
                    String tags = sw.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(this, tags, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                vendor_profile_enter_tags.getText().clear();
                mTagContainerLayout.setTheme(ColorFactory.NONE);

            }

        });
```